# prove that $M$ and $M'$ are antipodal on the circumcircle and $MM'$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, homothety

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let $I,I_a, I_b,I_c$ denote the incenter, the A-excenter, the B-excenter and the C-excenter of ABC respectively. Let $M$ and $M'$ be the midpoints of $II_a$ and $I_bI_c.$

1. Prove that $M$ and $M'$ are antipodal on the circumcircle of ABC and $MM'$ is the perpendicular bisector of BC.
2. Prove that the circumradius of the excentral circle is $2R.$

For reference, below is a picture to help visualize the problem.

[image]

I know that $ABC$ is the orthic triangle of $I_a I_bI_c$ and its circumcircle is the nine-point circle $C$ of $I_a I_bI_c$. Also $C$ passes through $M$ and $M'$ as well as the midpoint of $I_bI_c$, of $I_a I_c$, of $I_c I,$ and of $I_bI.$ $IBI_aC$ is also cyclic with $M$ at its center. I need to show that $M,O,M'$ are collinear and $MM'$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and passes through its midpoint, say $M_1.$ This follows from the fact that $OB = OC = OM,$ where $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABC$ and the fact that $BM=MC$ since $I B I_aC$ is inscribed in a circle centred at M. But why are $M$ and $M'$ antipodal? It suffices to show that $M'$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $BC,$ since then $M,O,M'$ would all be collinear.

For the proof of 2), I found a proof [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/CircumradiusOfExcentralTriangle.shtml), but I don't fully understand solution 1. In solution 1, how would one prove the nine-point circle's center get sent by the homothety to the circumcenter of $I_aI_a I_c$?

Comment: Its well known that $M$ is the midpoint of arc $BC$. Its also well known the circle is the nine point circle of the excentral triangle, so the midpoint lies on it. So we need to show that the midpoint is just the midpoint of the major arc $BC$. Try to think of the excentral triangle as the reference triangle and prove the more general statement about any triangle and it's nine point circle (recall $A,B,C$ are the altitude feet in this triangle).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, we need to show that $M'$ is the midpoint of major arc $BC$. Its sufficient to prove that in a general triangle $XYZ$, the midpoint of $YZ$ is the midpoint of the major arc formed by the altitude feet of $Y$ and $Z$ on the nine point circle. If the feet are $E,F$ and the midpoint is $G$ its sufficient to show $GE=GF$ (because $G$ is on the circle as mentioned in the comments). This is true since $G$ is the center of cyclic $YZEF$. The second problem is then trivial because $IOM$ and $II'I_a$ are homothetic by one of the other problems you posted.