# Show that the lines $AX',BY',CZ'$ are concurrent.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, circles

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let $P$ be a point so that $AP,BP,CP$ intersect $BC,CA,AB$ at 3 noncollinear points $X,Y,Z$. Let circle $C_1$ pass through $X,Y,Z$. Let $C_1$ intersect the lines $BC,CA,AB$ again at $X',Y',Z'$ (let $X'=X$ if $C_1$ only intersects $AP$ once). Prove that the lines $AX',BY',CZ'$ are concurrent.

I think it would be useful to split the proof into two cases, one where $P$ is in $ABC$ and another where $P$ is outside of $ABC$. One should be able to use Ceva's theorem to conclude the result. First consider the case where $P$ is inside triangle $ABC.$ If $X,Y,Z$ are on the incircle of $ABC$ the result is obvious. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

> Edit: [this link](http://math.fau.edu/yiu/AEG2016/20160803.pdf) has the solution.

Comment: Power of a point. Source?

Comment: Google "cyclocevian conjugate".

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks, I suspected it had a name based on its simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $BZ\cdot BZ’=BX\cdot BX’$, etc. by power of a point so we’re done by Ceva twice.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at some of my other geometry questions if you have time? Here are the links: [q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546098/prove-that-the-two-centers-of-similitude-of-two-circles-with-distinct-centersdiv), [q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546093/prove-the-perpendiculars-from-the-three-excenters-to-the-corresponding-sides-con), and [q3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546086/prove-that-m-and-m-are-antipodal-on-the-circumcircle-and-mm-is-the-perpe).

Comment: @user33096 I answered q2 and q3, q1 has been answered in the comments.